# Apache Airflow correct sheduler date

Tags: airflow, directed-acyclic-graphs

why is my Apache Airflow scheduler resetting milliseconds at 00:00 UTС. I am doing a per-minute retrieval of data for the previous minute and due to this adjustment I am losing my data.
[image]

Comment: I am not sure why - but if you start scheduling your job to start from ms 00:00, then you wouldn't' have this problem, right? Also, a minute retrieval kind of operation seems a but more suited for a streaming-esque kind of approach rather than this micro-batching

Comment: the problem is that for some reason the airflow jumps from 23:58 and goes straight to 00:00 skipping 23:59. At the same time, we see that for some reason it resets milliseconds and seconds and starts from 00. Would you suggest setting the start of execution from the exact time and not the enable button?

Comment: Yes, you could try that.